# HTML+CSS - html fullscreen

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I am using

```
div {width: 100%; height: 100%}
```

because I need to have a div which should be "full screen-ed" on the beginning of my page. I've read that I need to set

```
html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}
```

too. It looks great but after this I have some content. Here my problem begins. HTML still have only the height which was set by **height: 100%**. And content below only overflows from html tag. Is there any way to avoid this problem only with CSS and HTML ? I can do it with javascript but I would like to do it another way.

Thanks for your answers.

P.S.: http://honzakopecky.8u.cz/masaze/

Comment: You need to hide after 100% height or to auto-grow after 100%?

Comment: Fiddle, please... I'm old-fashioned

Comment: `body {min-height: 100%}`?

Comment: yep that @popnoodles or to hide `body {overflow:hidden}`

Comment: I need it to auto-grow. I've tried min-height but then it doesn't make that div "fullscreen-ed".

Comment: Noone knows any solution for my problem?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing using just height? Many sites use this method and the overflow isn't a cause for concern, even when displaying mobile versions.

Comment: I know it isn't problem but it isn't "valid" (html and body just should cover whole content, don't you think?). Do you think that there is no other solution except overflow?

Answer (score 1):

You have stumbled across a bug existing in (at least) Chrome and Firefox. I don't know how many browsers are affected, but it's certainly in those two.

When an element has height: 100% then it will correctly inherit from a parent which has a defined height but it will not inherit from a parent with min-height. It's almost as if the browser doesn't recognize the parent's height at all when using min-height.

The only thing you can do to get around this bug, is use javascript like you mentioned, or relative/absolute positioning. For example:

```
html, body { min-height: 100%; }
body { position: relative; }
section { position: absolute; }
```

You may need to tinker with your top, left, right, and bottom on the section element but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
min-height: 100vh
width: 100%
```

for the div and don`t give any width and height to the html or body tag.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you must to apply `*`. It means set margin and paddings of ALL elements to 0. Because the browser applying different values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            background-color:red;
        }
        div {
            background-color:blue;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> text </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability.